# Equalize WPF Canvas children size

Tags: wpf, canvas, layout

I have a custom canvas and i have implemented **MeasureOverride** and **ArrangeOverride** methods.

At **ArrangeOverride** phase I want to calculate max element width and set all element's width to that value.

I am calling this method, but nothing happens.

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
{
     var maxWidth = 400;
     foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
     {
          child.Arrange(new Rect(GetLeft(child), GetTop(child), maxWidth , child.DesiredSize.Height));
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you hit a breakpoint inside ArrangeOverride? Any visible errors?

Comment: no errors, no warnings

Comment: Breakpoint...? Is the method ever called?

Comment: did you found solution, am having the same issue, can you share your solution